# What is the exact reason behind Twitter API 403 statusCode?

Tags: twitter

I am getting statusCode 403 from Twitter API call 'statuses/retweet/:id'. The documentation says it is due to rate limit. But I am not RTing too frequently. [image: Description of 403 from Twitter Documentation]

The returned message from Twitter is

```
twitterReply: '{"errors":"sharing is not permissible for this status (Share validations failed)"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The "Sharing is not permissible" usually relates to one of the following:

- The user has forbidden retweets.
- You have already retweeted that tweet.
- The tweet has been deleted.
- You have been blocked by the user.
- The tweet is your own (you cannot retweet yourself).

Are you able to retweet any other tweets?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll check the exact reason in my case. I'll mark it answered after analysing my case. Thanks again.